# How to reduce boilerplate nested Result in Rust

Tags: rust

I have code using a nested `Result` like this:

```
fn ip4(s: &str) -> Result<(u8, u8, u8, u8), num::ParseIntError> {
    let t: Vec<_> = s.split('.').collect();
    match t[0].parse::<u8>() {
        Ok(a1) => {
            match t[1].parse::<u8>() {
                Ok(a2) => {
                    match t[2].parse::<u8>() {
                        Ok(a3) => {
                            match t[3].parse::<u8>() {
                                Ok(a4) => {
                                    Ok((a1, a2, a3, a4))
                                }
                                Err(er) => Err(er)
                            }
                        },
                        Err(er) => Err(er)
                    }
                }
                Err(er) => Err(er)
            }
        }
        Err(er) => Err(er),
    }
}
```

Is there any function or composing way to reduce this? Something like Haskell or Scala programmers do:

```
fn ip4(s: &str) -> Result<(u8, u8, u8, u8), num::ParseIntError> {
  let t: Vec<_> = s.split('.').collect();
  Result
  .lift((,,,))
  .ap(() -> t[0].parse::<u8>())
  .ap(() -> t[1].parse::<u8>())
  .ap(() -> t[2].parse::<u8>())
  .ap(() -> t[3].parse::<u8>()) // maybe more concise in Haskell or Scala but I think it's enough :)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to your direct question is [the questionmark operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-) which would allow you to replace your whole `match` block with

```
Ok((
    t[0].parse::<u8>()?,
    t[1].parse::<u8>()?,
    t[2].parse::<u8>()?,
    t[3].parse::<u8>()?,
))
```

where essentially `?` will return the error immediately if one is encountered.

That said, Rust already provides APIs for parsing IP addresses. Even if you wanted to maintain your tuple approach (though why would you), you could implement your function as

```
fn ip4(s: &str) -> Result<(u8, u8, u8, u8), net::AddrParseError> {
    let addr: net::Ipv4Addr = s.parse()?;
    let octets = addr.octets();
    Ok((octets[0], octets[1], octets[2], octets[3]))
}
```

or just pass around the `Ipv4Addr` value directly.

Answer (score 1):

Though, I do not see anything bad in @loganfsmyth's answer, I want to add another solution.

Your problem is a very simple and general problem of all programming languages which can be solved very easily if you would have enough time or practice in optimizing solutions. There is some divide and conquer recursive technique which is usually used to solve such problems. For a start, imagine a more simple thing: parsing a single octet from a string. This is a simple parse which you already know. Then mentally try to expand this problem to a larger one - parsing all octets which is a simple **repeating** process of the smallest problem we have solved earlier (parsing a single octet). This leads us to an iterative/recursive process: **do something until**. Keeping this in mind I have rewritten your function to a simple iterative process which uses **tail-recursion** which will not cause a stack overflow as a usual recursion due to it's form:

```
use std::num;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct IpAddressOctets(pub u8, pub u8, pub u8, pub u8);
type Result = std::result::Result<IpAddressOctets, num::ParseIntError>;

fn ipv4(s: &str) -> Result {
    let octets_str_array: Vec<_> = s.split('.').collect();

    // If it does not contain 4 octets then there is a error.
    if octets_str_array.len() != 4 {
        return Ok(IpAddressOctets(0, 0, 0, 0))  // or other error type
    }

    let octets = Vec::new();

    fn iter_parse(octets_str_array: Vec<&str>, mut octets: Vec<u8>) -> Result {
        if octets.len() == 4 {
            return Ok(IpAddressOctets(octets[0], octets[1], octets[2], octets[3]))
        }

        let index = octets.len();
        octets.push(octets_str_array[index].parse::<u8>()?);
        iter_parse(octets_str_array, octets)
    }

    iter_parse(octets_str_array, octets)
}

fn main() {
    println!("IP address octets parsed: {:#?}", ipv4("10.0.5.234"));
}
```

Keep in mind that `Rust` language is a bit more functional than you might think.

Also, I would recommend you to read [this book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) which greatly explains the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've read the SICP book :D; my question is related to reduce boilerplate made by nested Result.

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o yes, I have just noticed that your initial solution could be a bit better if you would rewrite it as an iterative process. But of course I would prefer using `Rust` standard library instead of writing this code :) Just wanted to point you that if you don't have such a solution as @loganfsmyth you may do it better anyway :)

Comment: There is some inefficiency here, part of which was present in the original solution to be honest. You do not have to `collect` the result of `split` into a `Vec` (causing a memory allocation), you can directly use the resulting iterator. And if you do so, you get all the iterator goodness.

Comment: @MatthieuM. nice point, but will I be able to check the size of the split then?

Comment: You can count as you consume the iterator.

Comment: @MatthieuM. so we will have to produce iterator twice, one for counting, another for operations.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: **No!** This would be wasteful. *as you consume* means *at the same time you consume*. I would use `enumerate` here so that the iterator produce a tuple `(index of element, element)`. Keep the last index, it tells you (after the fact) how many elements the iterator yielded.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, as you may see, I return from the function immediately if the split does not contain enough elements because there is no need in continuing the process. Doing as you say will produce, for example, 3 iterations and will cause a error only on 4th time - we have wasted the cpu with useless work.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: Maybe, maybe not. You already iterated 4 times to create the `octets_str_array` in the first place + allocated memory (possibly twice or thrice depending on the initial size of the vector allocation). In terms of worst case latency, memory allocation is unbounded (it may trigger the OOM killer which will kill a process and harvest its memory), so as far as worst case is concerned, you can "waste" a lot of CPU cycles whilst still being much better off than with memory allocation! Of course... this tells us nothing about average case...

Answer (score 1):

You can use early returns to prevent the nesting (but not the repetition).

Note the body of the `Err` arms of the matches:

```
fn ip4(s: &str) -> Result<(u8, u8, u8, u8), num::ParseIntError> {
    let t: Vec<_> = s.split('.').collect();

    let a1 = match t[0].parse::<u8>() {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(er) => return Err(er),
    };
    let a2 = match t[1].parse::<u8>() {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(er) => return Err(er),
    };
    let a3 = match t[2].parse::<u8>() {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(er) => return Err(er),
    };
    let a4 = match t[3].parse::<u8>() {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(er) => return Err(er),
    };

    (a1, a2, a3, a4)
}
```

But, as the others have said, Rust already has a built-in way to parse IP addresses.

Comment: FYI, this `match/return` pattern is just what the question-mark operator does. The only difference is that it wraps the error as `Err(From::from(err))`.